# To add a condition dynamically in PowerBuilder

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

I'm new to Power Builder code. I need to add a condition to Join dynamically. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot

String szdSQL, psql, sznewsql

```
   szdSQL = "Select A, B, C, D 
   FROM  sy_staging
   LEFT OUTER JOIN fd_M
   ON sy_staging.id = fd_M.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN gl_M
   ON sy_staging.id= gl_M.id AND sy_staging.version = gl_M.version
   WHERE sy_staging.year = :lyear AND
   sy_staging.location = :llocation "
```

**psql = "Upper(fd_M.code3) = 'SMM' "**
In my new query I want to add the condition present in this string variable (psql) in the join as below

```
sznewsql = " "Select A, B, C, D 
   FROM  sy_staging
   LEFT OUTER JOIN fd_M
   ON sy_staging.id = fd_M.id AND Upper(fd_M.code3) = 'SMM'
   LEFT OUTER JOIN gl_M
   ON sy_staging.id= gl_M.id AND sy_staging.version = gl_M.version
   WHERE sy_staging.year = :lyear AND
   sy_staging.location = :llocation "
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...  That's an interesting case - adding a parameter to the ON clause, not the WHERE clause.

I'd use a datawindow, for sure (because I always do), but I'm not sure you can do that in graphic mode.  You might have to convert to syntax, and then just add the new parameter into the ON clause with the ":" syntax.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN fd_M  
ON sy_staging.id = fd_M.id AND Upper(fd_M.code3) = :newStringParm  
LEFT OUTER JOIN gl_M
...
```

and then your PowerScript would be
dw_1.retrieve( lYear, lLocation, psql )

-Paul Horan-

Comment: Thanks Paul for your response. But I cannot add a parameter to the ON clause. As in PB application we need to add that condition dynamically after selecting a criteria from the drop down list.

Comment: If you use a datawindow you can change the sql in the sqlpreview event (which is called by the dw.retrieve method) and modify it based on the value in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to have those two different SQLs, you could just create two separate datawindows and then dynamically swap out the one used in the datawindow control.